# Random number between 80 and 120 java

Tags: java, random, numbers

I need to create a random number between 80 and 120, I was given the line

```
int tempF = (-17 + (int) (Math.random() * ((-20 - (-17)) + 1)));
```

and I added the line

```
Random generator = new Random();
```

above it, but I'm not sure where to go from here?

Comment: Do you claim any relation between the line you were "given" and your requirement? The relation (if any) is not exactly obvious.

Comment: `Random rand = new Random(); int number = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
Random ran = new Random();
int x = ran.nextInt(10); //where 10 is range
```